# Enabling, disabling certain columns WPF Toolkit datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, toolkit

I am trying to create a WPF toolkit datagrid with following format. I was able to hide content 
for the columns in LoadingRow event of the data grid. But the last column is a button and not sure how I can hide the content for that. It should only displayed once per each name. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this ?

[image]

Thanks
DM

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <Button Content="Delete"
               Visibility="{Binding CanDelete, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

CanDelete is a bool property on your Row Binding on your List , change it to true when needed PropertyChanged + Binding will do the rest.